# Most effective way to find connected cells in matrix

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matrix

I have a matrix (max size 100 x 100) with numeric values and need to find there the most effective (minimum number of cells) set of **connected** cells that sum up to the requested value. This matrix also can have negative cells (internal walls of matrix) which algorithm should be able to walk around. I don’t need to take into account diagonal cells (only up, down, left, right) when looking for connected cells.

For example we have the following matrix:

1 4 4

1 1 2

4 -1 1

If we are looking for cells set that sum up to:

- 9 the right result is: 4(0x2), 4(0x1), 1(0x0 or 1x1)
- 3 the right result is: 2(1x2), 1(1x1 or 2x2)
- 5 the right result is: 4(0x1), 1(0x0 or 1x1)

What is the most efficient way to find these connected cells as recursion will work VERY slow when matrix gets relatively big (like 50x50)? Or is matrix representation of these data not the best way for this task?

Thanks

Comment: How big are the values in the matrix? Ho big is the result you are looking for?

Comment: This looks like a harder [Subset sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) problem, which would mean, that you will run into (performance) trouble without some additional assumptions about your data. My first approach would be: get all unique values; loop over these, calculate all connected_components and use some subset-sum algorithm (very informal description; assumption: n_unique << N*N)

Comment: @Sorin Values are relatively small. Most of the time cell value will be up to 4, very rare up to 16 and I don't think that the result that we will be looking for will ever be greater than 20.

Comment: @sascha Exactly, it's relatively easy to find result using recursion, but it takes way too long even for 50x50 matrix (because we are looking for best result and pretty much have to find all the connected sets). Maybe there is a way to prepare intermediate result or convert matrix into something that works better for this purpose

Comment: Is your recursive algorithm starting from every cell and walking in every direction, or have you already implemented some optimisations? Do you have a method to avoid checking duplicate combinations, like skipping C+B+A if you've already checked A+B+C? Do you limit the recursion depth to the shortest sequence found so far?

Comment: @m69 Yep and it definitely helped, but it's still slow, taking into account that target is to get result ready in 1 sec or worst case 3 sec (first run can take longer if we need to prepare intermediate result and keep it in memory). I hoped that limiting the recursion depth to the shortest sequence found so far will give really big performance boost and it did in some cases, but sometime we have matrix 90% filled with the same values and in these cases we still end up looking for almost all sets.

Comment: Could you perhaps post one or more examples of a matrix and a target, with the number of recursions your algorithm needs to find the solution? Something sized 10x10 or 20x20 should be enough to test different strategies.

Comment: @m69 Here you go https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2bcy0dauriCOWpZN053b0hCNTQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: In examples A, C, D, E and F, the -1 entries separate the matrix into multiple connected components of positions.  If you are not allowed to pick up negative numbers (i.e. they serve *only* to indicate squares you can't pick up) then you could easily discover these components and solve each one independently, for a large savings in time.

Comment: In a similar vein, in example G, turning cell E4 into a -1 would partition the problem into 2 connected components of roughly half the size of the original problem.  So you could look for such cells (this can be done in linear time; google "articulation point"), solve each resulting component independently (keeping the original cell value there, but pretending that the rest of the matrix is all -1s), and then (if none of them yields a solution) look for solutions that involve at least one of these cells as well as at least 1 cells in two of the components it borders.

Comment: One more suggestion to improve brute-force: Remove as many symmetries as you can.  E.g. every connected set of cells has, among its topmost cells, a leftmost such cell.  That means that at each (x, y) position, you need only look for connected cell sets that never go above the initial cell, and if it goes to the left of the initial cell, remains strictly below it.

Comment: Thank you, guys! I'm going to try your suggestions and will let you know about outcome

Comment: I started writing some code to try out my suggestions, and after creating a histogram of the positive values and then generating the partitions, the logical next step seems to be to create an adjacency list. For each positive-number-cell you'd store a list of neighbouring positive number-cells (and cells connected through one or more zero-cells). This should speed up the rest of the algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

### NP-hardness

As suggested by sascha in the comments, this problem is NP-hard, so it's unlikely that an efficient (polynomial-time) solution exists.  Here is a reduction from the [Subset Sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) problem, where we are given a target value m and a multiset of n numbers, and are asked whether it is possible to find a submultiset of these n numbers that sum to m:

1. Create a matrix row containing all n values of the Subset Sum problem, in any order.
2. Create a second matrix row below it, containing the value 0 in every cell.
3. Solve your problem on the resulting matrix, using m as the target value.

Now any solution can pick up the entire row of 0 values, and then choose *any subset* of cells in the top row since they are all connected to the second row.  So if the Subset Sum problem has a solution, then your problem has a corresponding solution, and vice versa.

Subset Sum is an NP-hard problem, and the above shows a way to solve an arbitrary Subset Sum problem by turning it into an instance of your problem and then solving that problem, so your problem must be NP-hard as well.

### If only positive numbers can be picked

I'm assuming above that zero values can appear in the matrix (and can be picked).  If OTOH only positive numbers can be picked, the reduction can be adjusted:

Let z be one more than the sum of the absolute values of all n input numbers to the Subset Sum problem.  Instead of a single row of 0 values, make a row of z values; and instead of taking m to be the target, take m+nz.  Clearly if there was a solution to the SS problem then we can get a solution to our problem by picking the particular numbers in the top row that were picked by the SS solution, as well as all n copies of the z value on the bottom row.  I'll now show that the other direction works too: that is, if we can get the target of m+nz in the constructed instance of your problem, then it must use all n copies of the z value in the bottom row, leaving exactly a total of m in the top row, corresponding to a solution to the original SS instance.

Suppose we have a solution to the constructed instance that hits the target of m+nz.  Then every cell in the bottom row must be part of this solution, because if even one such cell is not, then we couldn't reach a sum of nz (let alone the possibly greater value m+nz) even if we included *every* element in the top row, since (by design) z > sum(all elements in the top row).  (I'm assuming m is positive here.)

Comment: Yep, only positive numbers can be picked (0 - define placeholder, -1 - walls of matrix). There is one more value (-2 - marked when cell was previously taken), but it's really has the same purpose as -1.

Answer (score 2):

To try and reduce the number of recursions to a minimum, I'd try this approach, which looks for sequences of cells that add up to the target from short to long, so that you find the shortest possible solution first:

Given a target, e.g. `10`, and a matrix, e.g.

```
[1, 0, 1, 2, 3]
[6, 1, 4, 0, 2]
[1, 2, 4,-2, 3]
[1,-1, 2, 3, 1]
[0, 2, 3, 0, 1]
```

- Count the occurance of every positive value in the matrix:

```
1: 6, 2: 5, 3: 4, 4: 2, 5: 0, 6: 1
```

- Find all partitions of the target using the available values:

```
6,4  
6,3,1
6,2,2
6,2,1,1
6,1,1,1,1
4,4,2
4,4,1,1
4,3,3
4,3,2,1
4,3,1,1,1
4,2,2,2
4,2,2,1,1
4,2,1,1,1,1
4,1,1,1,1,1,1
3,3,3,1
3,3,2,2
3,3,2,1,1
3,3,1,1,1,1
3,2,2,2,1
3,2,2,1,1,1
3,2,1,1,1,1,1
2,2,2,2,2
2,2,2,2,1,1
2,2,2,1,1,1,1
2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1
```

(Since the target is quite small, the number of partitions shouldn't be huge. The maximum number of partitions is only 627 if the target is 20.)

- Sort the partitions from short to long:

```
6,4  
6,3,1
6,2,2
4,4,2
4,3,3
6,2,1,1
...
```

- Starting with the shortest partition, try to locate it in the matrix:

  - Find the locations of the largest number, mark the cell as included in the selection and recurse with the rest of the partition.
  - Try to grow the selection with neighbouring numbers from the partition.
  - If you cannot find the complete partition, skip to the next partition.

If there are zeros in the matrix which can be included in the selection, then, whenever the partition length increases (e.g. when you move from `4,3,3` to `6,2,1,1`, retry the shorter partitions padded with zeros (if enough are available).

If the values in the matrix are quite random, i.e. not specifically designed to make it difficult to find a solution, then I think this method should reduce the number of necessary recursions substantially. (I haven't tried to code it, so I can't give a good estimate.)

Comment: I think this should definitely help if there is usually a way to make the sum using a small number of cells, because it's really the only way to avoid enumerating at least some longer sequences.  (BTW, the subproblem you solve for each partition in turn is the NP-hard Graph Motif problem, so there's no reason to expect it will be fast in the worst case.)